# SugarCRM 7 override auto-increment field

Tags: sugarcrm

Through a logichook, I'm trying to insert a new Quote record through the bean class.  The "quote_num" field is an auto-increment field.  When I try this code below, instead of inserting in MySQL with the quote_num i specify, it uses the next number in the auto-increment sequence.  I know I could just use an SQL INSERT but I'm trying to stick to the bean.  Any ideas?

```
$newQuote = new Quote();
$newQuote->name = "Web Order";
$newQuote->quote_num = 902011;
$newQuote->quote_order_c = $orderorcredit;
$newQuote->save();
```

Comment: Hope this link will help u https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/28762-autoincrement-field

Answer (score 0):

For Auto Increment : You can do like below ,

```
 $count = "SELECT IFNULL(MAX(your field), 0) as count  FROM table;             

                $count = '';
                while ($row = $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($result)) {
                    $count_coc = $row['count'];
                }
                $bean->ignore_update = true;
                $bean->number_c = $count_coc + 1;
                $bean->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Your example shows me how to autoincrement through code.  My problem is that the autoincrement is happening at the MySQL level and I'm trying to avoid the auto increment using the bean in Sugar rather than an SQL statement.

Comment: could you elaborate more clearly what result you want.

Comment: Quote_num is an auto increment field. Let's say it's at 200000. If I use the sugar bean ($newQuote->quote_num)and assign 900000 as the quote_num it ignores 900000 and just inserts into the DB as 200001 as it's the next number in the auto-increment sequence.  I want to manually insert a number higher than the next increment while using the sugar bean.

Comment: You will have to modify the auto-increment in the database level and remove auto increment feature from the field.